# Hydrolysis of polyamides using solid acid catalyst

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, catalysis, hydrolysis, amides

The neutral hydrolysis of polyamides (eg. nylon 6,6) does not go to completion as the reaction is reversible. You can get around this by carrying out the reaction in an acidic/basic medium. With acid catalysed hydrolysis, the final amine product is protonated. This prevents it from reacting with the carboxylic acid formed.

My question is, will using a solid acid catalyst (eg. Zeolites) allow the reaction to go to completion as with a homogeneous catalyst (eg. HCl)?

Comment: With an acid catalyst only a proportion of the amine ends up protonated. Soundsl ike you need more than 1 eq of acid to protonate all the amine that is formed.